# How to Create Multiple Cursors in a single Range Slider?

Tags: html, css

Pretty Straightforward. Creating a Range slider with a single cursor is easy:

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

[image]

But what if  I'd like to add 2 or more cursors ?

Comment: Give a try at this Pen https://codepen.io/jackiejohnston/pen/NNrpjQ?editors=1010

Comment: @PrathapG thanks, that's a lot of JS code to achieve the effect. whoa!

Comment: I was surprised by looking at the JS too